# How to mwl list according to AE (DCM4CHEE)

Tags: dcm4che

I have been working in setting up multiple AE titles and configured two AE called CLIENT1 and CLIENT2.

Now I have send hl7 order for these two AEs but at modality end i could fetch all the worklist irrespective of AE.

Could anyone of you please tell how to configure AEs in hl7 orm message we send and also how  we fetch worklist according to AE

Thanks
Neeraja

Answer (score 0):

This problem I got resolved by MWL item coerce i.e.,c-find request by using a mwl-cfindrq.xsl  on ...server/default/conf/dcm4chee-ae/ having Scheduled Station AE striclty in ORM message we send.